# CSS label:before - show icon before the label only on :hover and :active

Tags: css, label

I'm fiddling with only HTML+CSS tabs here: http://jsfiddle.net/75c0cveg/

Currently I've got an icon showing before the label in each tab. The icon is currently showing for all button states.

Here is the CSS

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 3px solid #006372;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

I am struggling to figure out how can I achieve that the icon before the label will only show up on :hover and :active states?

If the tab is not active, the icon should not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply transform this CSS :

```
label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }
```

into this :

```
input:checked + label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:checked + label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:checked + label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }
```

and for the hover state you may add this :

```
input:hover + label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:hover + label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:hover + label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input:checked+label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

input:checked+label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

input:checked+label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

input:hover+label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

input:hover+label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

input:hover+label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 3px solid #006372;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">CONTACT 1</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">CONTACT 2</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">CONTACT 3</label>

  <section id="content1">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 1: 111111111111
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 2: 222222222222
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content3">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 3: 333333333333
    </p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
label:before {
    display: none;
}
label:hover:before, input:checked + label:before {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Under "active", I suppose, you are referring to the case when the tab is actually checked?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
label:before {
  display: none;
}
label:hover:before, input:checked + label:before {
  display: inline-block;
}
label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 3px solid #006372;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">CONTACT 1</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">CONTACT 2</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">CONTACT 3</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 1: 111111111111 
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 2: 222222222222 
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 3: 333333333333 
    </p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the **[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)** state by chaining the **[pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)** together as `:hover:before`:

```
label[for*='1']:hover:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='2']:hover:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='3']:hover:before { content: '\f095'; }
```

Note that `:hover` must come **before** `:before`.

To target the **[`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)** state, you'll need to get a little more creative, and instead target the `label` that follows the `input` which is **[`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)** with the **[adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**:

```
input:checked + label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:checked + label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:checked + label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }
```

Note that considering you're setting the exact same content in all six scenarios,
 you might as well chain them together as:

```
label[for*='1']:hover:before,
label[for*='2']:hover:before,
label[for*='3']:hover:before,
input:checked + label[for*='1']:before,
input:checked + label[for*='2']:before,
input:checked + label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f095';
}
```

The tabs can be seen working on both `:active` and `:hover` in the following example:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:hover:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='2']:hover:before { content: '\f095'; }
label[for*='3']:hover:before { content: '\f095'; }

input:checked + label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:checked + label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f095'; }
input:checked + label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f095'; }

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 3px solid #006372;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">CONTACT 1</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">CONTACT 2</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">CONTACT 3</label>

  <section id="content1">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 1: 111111111111
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 2: 222222222222
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content3">
    <p>This is CONTACT TEL 3: 333333333333
    </p>
  </section>

</main>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle for this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6y23en6x/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No problem; it was an interesting one to work out :)